# How to reuse the nested Resource methods in the encompassing Resource methods?

Tags: rest, flask, nested-resources, flask-restx

I have a resource called `Profile` which nests a list of `Port` resources like so:

```json
{
        "profile": "abcd"
        "ports": [
            {
                "port": "5687"
                "state": "state"
                "protocol": "protocol"
                "direction": "direction"
            }
        ]
 }
```

The `profile` key uniquely identifies the `Profile` resource and the `ports` key represents the nested list of `Port` resources.  The `port` key in the `Port` resource uniquely identifies a port for the given `Profile`.

The two Resources are modeled like so:

```py
PortModel = api.model("Port", 
    {
        "port": fields.String(required=True),
        "state": fields.String(required=True),
        "protocol": fields.String(),
        "direction": fields.String()
    },
)

ProfileModel = api.model("Profile",
    {
        "profile": fields.String(required=True),
        "ports": fields.List(fields.Nested(PortModel), required=True),
    },
)
```

The skeleton implementation of the two Resources is given below:

```py
class Profile(Resource):    
    @api.expect(ProfileModel)
    def post(self):
        pass

class PortsList(Resource):
    @api.expect([PortModel])
    def post(self, profile):
        pass
```

Then the routes are as given below:

```py
api.add_resource(Profile, "api/v1.0/profiles/")
api.add_resource(PortsList, "/api/v1.0/profiles/<profile>/ports")
```

Question:

When a POST request comes to `/api/v1.0/profiles/<profile>/ports` with the following body:

```json
[
    {
        "port": "5687"
        "state": "state"
        "protocol": "protocol"
        "direction": "direction"
    }
]
```

the backend should create the list of `Port` resources for the given profile.

Similarly, when a POST request comes to `api/v1.0/profiles` with the following body:

```json
{
    "profile": "abcd"
    "ports": [
        {
            "port": "5687"
            "state": "state"
            "protocol": "protocol"
            "direction": "direction"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Is it possible for the `post` method of `Profile` resource to automatically invoke and reuse the `post` method of `Port` resource passing to it the `profile` which uniquely identifies the `Profile` resource? If so, do I need to write my own code or the framework has the capability to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, does it make sense to create a common Python function to handle the logic of the ports, and call this function from both endpoints?

```
def handle_ports(profile, ports):
    ... # Process your ports

class Profile(Resource):    
    @api.expect(ProfileModel)
    def post(self):
        handle_ports(
            request.json.get('profile'),
            request.json.get('ports')
        )
        ... # Do additional stuff for this endpoint

class PortsList(Resource):
    @api.expect([PortModel])
    def post(self, profile):
        handle_ports(
            profile,
            request.json.get('ports')
        )
```